# showing that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Show that
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2+ y^2}{x-y} & x \ne y \\ 1 & x=y \end{cases}$$
> is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

I was trying this question by showing that the limit of the function at $(0,0)$ is not equal to $1$, i.e. the value of the function at $(0,0)$. But I am getting this same. I am trying it by putting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, and I am stuck here.

Comment: Just try $f(x,0)$.

Comment: Why do you think there is a limit at $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the path to $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis. For all points on the $x$-axis, we have $y=0$. So

$$ \lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x}=0.$$

On the other hand consider the path along $y=x$:

$$ \lim_{(x,x)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,x)\to (0,0)} 1 = 1.$$

So two distinct paths to the origin yield different limits and we conclude $f(x,y)$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suposse $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$, since the path $g(t)=(2t,t)$ is continuous, then $f\circ g$ is continuos at $0$, hence $f\circ g(t)\to f(g(0))=f(0,0)=1$ when $t\to 0^+$. But this is not true, because $f\circ g(t)=5t\to 0$ when $t\to 0^+$, then $f$ is not continuos at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Strange function!  Other than $(0,0)$, the function becomes infinite near $x=y$, even if $=1$ along that line.  Specifically for $x\gt y$, $f(x,y)\to \infty$, while for $x\lt y$, $f(x,y)\to -\infty$.  Therefore as $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$, $f(x,y)$ will assume all real values, definitely not continuous!